# Algorithms find shortest path to all cells on grid

Tags: algorithm, actionscript-3, search, shortest-path

I have a grid [40 x 15] with 2 to 16 units on it, and unknown amount of obstacles.
How to find the shortest path to all the units from my unit location.

I have two helper methods that we can consider as O(1)

- getMyLocation() - return the (x, y) coordinates of my location on the grid
- investigateCell(x, y) - return information about cell at (x,y) coordinates

I implemented [A* search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A%2a_search_algorithm) algorithm, that search simultaneously to all the directions. At the end it output a grid where each cell have a number representing the distance from my location, and collection of all the units on the grid. It performs with O(N) where N is the number of cells - 600 in my case.

I implement this using AS3, unfortunately it takes my machine 30 - 50 milliseconds to calculate.

Here is my source code. Can you suggest me a better way?

```
package com.gazman.strategy_of_battle_package.map
{
    import flash.geom.Point;

    /**
     * Implementing a path finding algorithm(Similar to A* search only there is no known target) to calculate the shortest path to each cell on the map.
     * Once calculation is complete the information will be available at cellsMap. Each cell is a number representing the
     * number of steps required to get to that location. Enemies and Allies will be represented with negative distance. Also the enemy and Allys
     * coordinations collections are provided. Blocked cells will have the value 0.<br><br>
     * Worth case and best case efficiency is O(N) where N is the number of cells.
     */
    public class MapFilter
    {
        private static const PULL:Vector.<MapFilter> = new Vector.<MapFilter>();
        public var cellsMap:Vector.<Vector.<int>>;
        public var allys:Vector.<Point>;
        public var enemies:Vector.<Point>;
        private var stack:Vector.<MapFilter>;
        private var map:Map;
        private var x:int;
        private var y:int;
        private var count:int;
        private var commander:String;
        private var hash:Object;
        private var filtered:Boolean;

        public function filter(map:Map, myLocation:Point, commander:String):void{
            filtered = true;
            this.commander = commander;
            this.map = map;
            this.x = myLocation.x;
            this.y = myLocation.y;
            init();
            cellsMap[x][y] = 1;
            excecute();
            while(stack.length > 0){
                var length:int = stack.length;
                for(var i:int = 0; i < length; i++){
                    var mapFilter:MapFilter = stack.shift();
                    mapFilter.excecute();
                    PULL.push(mapFilter);
                }
            }
        }

        public function navigateTo(location:Point):Point{
            if(!filtered){
                throw new Error("Must filter before navigating");
            }
            var position:int = Math.abs(cellsMap[location.x][location.y]);
            if(position == 0){
                throw new Error("Target unreachable");
            }
            while(position > 2){
                if(canNavigateTo(position, location.x + 1, location.y)){
                    location.x++;
                }
                else if(canNavigateTo(position, location.x - 1, location.y)){
                    location.x--;
                }
                else if(canNavigateTo(position, location.x, location.y + 1)){
                    location.y++;
                }
                else if(canNavigateTo(position, location.x, location.y - 1)){
                    location.y--;
                }
                position = cellsMap[location.x][location.y];
            }

            return location;
            throw new Error("Unexpected filtering error");
        }

        private function canNavigateTo(position:int, targetX:int, targetY:int):Boolean
        {
            return isInMapRange(targetX, targetY) && cellsMap[targetX][targetY] < position && cellsMap[targetX][targetY] > 0;
        }

        private function excecute():void
        {
            papulate(x + 1, y);
            papulate(x - 1, y);
            papulate(x, y + 1);
            papulate(x, y - 1);
        }

        private function isInMapRange(x:int, y:int):Boolean{
            return x < cellsMap.length && 
                x >= 0 &&
                y < cellsMap[0].length && 
                y >= 0;
        }

        private function papulate(x:int, y:int):void
        {
            if(!isInMapRange(x,y) ||
                cellsMap[x][y] != 0 ||
                hash[x + "," + y] != null || 
                map.isBlocked(x,y)){
                return;
            }

            // we already checked that is not block
            // checking if there units
            if(map.isEmpty(x,y)){
                cellsMap[x][y] = count;
                addTask(x,y);
            }
            else{
                cellsMap[x][y] = -count;
                if(map.isAlly(x,y, commander)){
                    hash[x + "," + y] = true;
                    allys.push(new Point(x,y));
                }
                else {
                    hash[x + "," + y] = true;
                    enemies.push(new Point(x,y));
                }
            }
        }

        private function addTask(x:int, y:int):void
        {
            var mapFilter:MapFilter = PULL.pop();
            if(mapFilter == null){
                mapFilter = new MapFilter();
            }

            mapFilter.commander = commander;
            mapFilter.hash = hash;
            mapFilter.map = map;
            mapFilter.cellsMap = cellsMap;
            mapFilter.allys = allys;
            mapFilter..enemies = enemies;
            mapFilter.stack = stack;
            mapFilter.count = count + 1;
            mapFilter.x = x;
            mapFilter.y = y;
            stack.push(mapFilter);
        }

        private function init():void
        {
            hash = new Object();
            cellsMap = new Vector.<Vector.<int>>();
            for(var i:int = 0; i < map.width;i++){
                cellsMap.push(new Vector.<int>);
                for(var j:int = 0; j < map.height;j++){
                    cellsMap[i].push(0);
                }
            }   
            allys = new Vector.<Point>();
            enemies = new Vector.<Point>();
            stack = new Vector.<MapFilter>();
            count = 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is another SO question that might provide some acceptable alternative solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2748602/a-a-star-implementation-in-as3

Comment: A* depends heavily on the amount of obstacles. The really important question here is - are your obstacles dynamic? If not, there are pretty smart algorithms that precalculate all the possible options and cache them, so you just pick a path when you need it. Nevertheless, I don't find 30ms that bad.. What is your goal?

Comment: @AndreyPopov My goal is to reduce it below 1000 / 60 milliseconds. Because each of my 16 units need to perform this calculation on every turn. Also I build them in such way that they are completely independent and even may be uploaded by third party(in run time). So my obstacle are not dynamic, how ever my units are. And I do not know what is their or my location will be next turn.

Comment: What Andrey meant is, since your obstacles are not dynamic, the shortest path between two cells doesn't change, so you can calculate them beforehand and store them.

Comment: @MartonPallagi it's dynamic as units are also obstacles.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Floyd Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm) to find the shortest path between every pair of points. This would be `O(|V|^3)` and you would not have to run it for each unit, just once on each turn. It's such a simple algorithm I suspect it might be faster in practice than running something like [BFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) / [Bellman Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) for each unit.

Comment: My Algorithm have better performance. It's O(KV)(K number of units, V number of cells) and also Floyd Warshall do not return the details about the paths themselves.

Comment: I'm aware, 600, and 16 are such small numbers I was suggesting you try simpler algorithms that might be better in practice, not in theory. (And A* is O(|V|^2))